# highcharter xaxis crosshair tooltip labeling all series datapoints

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am trying to label all series datapoint on the crosshair tooltip when hovering over a timeseries. Here is what I currently have:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(
    type = "container", zoomType = "x") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>%
  hc_xAxis(
    tickLength = 0, 
    crosshair = TRUE
  ) %>%
  hc_yAxis(
    tickLength = 0, 
    crosshair = TRUE
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "line",
    data = airmiles
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "line",
    data = airmiles/2
  )
```

[image]

This is what I would like to have (or something similar):

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have two series and do you want to show them both at the tooltip try tu use xAxis.crosshair and tooltip.shared.

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
},
xAxis: {
    crosshair: true
},
```

Live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d4k8yqc7/

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared